CollectionView SelectedChangedCommand executes multiple times - .NET MAUI
I am using a CollectionView where I need to navigate to new page on SelectedChangedCommand.
But the command bound to SelectedChangedCommand execute multiple time for a single selection.
I have a nested CollectionView. For the parent CollectionView SelectionChangedCommand the bound command executes twice and for the Child CollectionView SelectionChangedCommand the bound command executes multiple times.
Please check this image for target UI
<CollectionView 
     x:Name="SpaceListCollectionView"
     Grid.Row="1" 
     SelectionMode="Single"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSpace}"
     SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding OnSpaceClicked}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding SpaceList}">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto">
                 <Grid
                         ColumnDefinitions="*,auto" 
                         RowDefinitions="auto,auto"
                         Padding="26,10,22,0"
                         BackgroundColor="#f8f8f8"
                         Grid.Row="0">
                     <Label 
                             Grid.Row="0" 
                             Grid.Column="0"
                             Text="{Binding Space}"
                             VerticalOptions="Center"
                             FontAttributes="Bold"
                             Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                     <Image 
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             Source="{Binding ArrowImage}"
                             WidthRequest="26"
                             VerticalOptions="Center"
                             Margin="0,0,0,7" />
                     <BoxView 
                             Grid.Row="1"
                             Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                             Color="#e7e7e7"
                             HeightRequest="1"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="End" />
                 </Grid>
                 <CollectionView                                    
                         Grid.Row="2"
                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Assets}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding BindingContext.SelectedAsset, Source={x:Reference HomePage}}"
                         SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding BindingContext.OnAssetClicked, Source={x:Reference HomePage}}"
                         SelectionMode="Single"
                         IsVisible="{Binding IsExpanded}">
                     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <Grid
                                         ColumnDefinitions="auto,*,auto"
                                         BackgroundColor="White"
                                         ColumnSpacing="20"
                                         Padding="10">
                                 <Image
                                             Grid.Column="0"
                                             Source="asset_ready.png" 
                                             HeightRequest="45"/>
                                 <Grid
                                             Grid.Column="1"
                                             RowDefinitions="auto,auto,auto"
                                             VerticalOptions="Center">
                                     <Label 
                                                 Grid.Row="0"
                                                 Text="{Binding AssetType}" 
                                                 FontSize="14" 
                                                 FontAttributes="Bold"
                                             IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.IsGroupBySpace, Source={x:Reference HomePage}}" />
                                     <Label 
                                             Grid.Row="0"
                                             Text="{Binding Space}" 
                                             FontSize="14" 
                                             IsVisible="{Binding BindingContext.IsGroupByAssetType, Source={x:Reference HomePage}}"
                                         FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                     <Label
                                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                                 Text="{Binding AssetName}"
                                                 FontSize="12" />
                                     <Label
                                                 Grid.Row="2"
                                                 Text="{Binding Barcode}"
                                                 FontSize="12" />
                                 </Grid>
                                 <Frame 
                                             Grid.Column="2"
                                             VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                             CornerRadius="50"
                                             Padding="8,3"
                                             BackgroundColor="#f0f0f0"
                                             BorderColor="Transparent">
                                     <Label 
                                                 Text="{Binding TaskCount}"
                                                 BackgroundColor="#f0f0f0"
                                         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                 </Frame>
                             </Grid>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 </CollectionView>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
 </CollectionView>

I tried to set Command.CanExecute(false); still the command executes.
I tried below solution as workaround but it failed. Click back to this page executes the OnAssetClicked Command.
private bool _canExecute;

   public ICommand OnAssetClicked => new Command(async () =>
   {
       if (_canExecute)
       {
           _canExecute = false;
           await AssetClicked();
       }
   });

   //Bound to Appearing EventToCommandBehavior
   public ICommand OnAppearing => new Command(Initialize); 

   Private void Initialize()
   {
      _canExecute = true;
   }

  //will be called on parent collection view item selected.
  private void Expand()
  {
      try
      {
          MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
          {
              var selectedSpace = SpaceList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Space == SelectedSpace?.Space);
              var index = SpaceList.IndexOf(selectedSpace ?? new AssetListModel());
              if (selectedSpace != null)
              {
                  selectedSpace.IsExpanded = !selectedSpace.IsExpanded;
                  if (selectedSpace.IsExpanded)
                  {
                      selectedSpace.ArrowImage = "key_up.png";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      selectedSpace.ArrowImage = "key_down.png";
                  }
                  SpaceList[index] = selectedSpace;
              }
          });
      }
      catch (Exception ex) when (ex != null)
      {
          Debug.WriteLine(ex + " in HomePageViewModel ExpandArea");
      }
      finally
      {
          SelectedSpace = null;
      }
  }

  //will be called on child collection view item selected
  private async Task AssetClicked()
  { 
      await NavigationService.Navigate(nameof(AssetDetailsPageView));
  }


How to stop SelectionChangedCommand from executing multiple times.

SelectionChanged "usually" fires at least once during "startup". Your templating approach is causing "many" collections to be created, causing many unsolicited "selection changes". You should really show a picture of what you want, and ask for ideas on how to best implement it.

May I ask what platform you are targeting on? And how do you set the BindingContext for the ContentPage? Much better if you could add more relevant code to help us reproduce this issue. Based on your code, it works well on my side.

Hi all,
Sure, I'll update my post with more details.

When you reset  SpaceList[index] = selectedSpace; at runtime, it causes the SelectedSpace to become null, So the method will execute twice. Please check my answer.

In the Expand method, you set SpaceList[index] = selectedSpace;, which causes the method executes twice.
If you want to change the IsExpanded property and notify the UI at runtime, you may implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your Space model like below.
public class SpaceModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Space { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Asset> Assets ...

    public bool isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get
        {
            return isExpanded;

        }
        set
        {
            isExpanded = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsExpanded)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}

Now when you change the IsExpand property of the Space Item, it will also notify the UI to change.Then you don't need to reset the value to SpaceList again. Just remove,
SpaceList[index] = selectedSpace;

For more info, you may refer to Viewmodels and property-change notifications, INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.
